# Redux mapStateToProps state in components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I get my action called in Redux Dev Tools and even the new state, but in the actual Component props is undefined.

The component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPromos } from '../../actions/promo';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Landing = ({ getPromos, data }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPromos();
    console.log(data) // ==>> "UNDEFINED"
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <section className='landing'>
        <div className='dark-overlay'>
          <div className='landing-inner'>
            <h1 className='x-large'> Developer Connector </h1>
            <p className='lead'>
              Create a developer profile/portfolio, share posts and get help
              from other developers
            </p>
            <div className='buttons'>
              <Link to='/register' className='btn btn-primary'>
                Sign Up
              </Link>
              <Link to='/login' className='btn btn-light'>
                Login
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

Landing.propTypes = {
  getPromos: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.data
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPromos }
)(Landing);
```

Actions:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';
import { GET_PROMOS, REGISTER_FAIL } from './types';

export const getPromos = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/promo');
    dispatch({
      type: GET_PROMOS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({ type: REGISTER_FAIL });
  }
};
```

And reducer:

```
import { GET_PROMOS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  data: null,
  title: ''
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_PROMOS:
      return { ...state, data: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Like I said, in Redux Dev Tools I get my desired output. But for some reason I cant get to echo this state in the component. What im getting wrong? Can it be something about the hooks?

Thanks !

Comment: can you show us your redux devtools reducer? What it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that jumps at me is that you have a naming conflict with the `getPromos` in your component, it's defined in the imports as `getPromos` then it's destructured in the component as `{ getPromos }` as well. I'm surprised you didn't get an error there for naming conflicts. 
You will want to NOT destructure `getPromos` in the component and instead call it as `(props) => { props.getPromos }` to actually call the connected action creator instead of the unconnected one.

Second, Is that reducer the main root reducer? or is it nested in the root reducer? if the latter is true then in your mapStateToProps the `data` prop should be one level deeper, as in `state: state.rootLevelState.data`
(sorry can't ask questions in the comments due to reputation < 50)

Comment: Yes, I have a combine reducers
`
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import alert from './alert';
import auth from './auth';
import promo from './promo';
export default combineReducers({ alert, auth, promo });
`

I tried removing the import of getPromos, and the code now its 

`
const Landing = props => {
  useEffect(props => {
    getPromos();

    console.log(props.getPromos);
  }, []);
`
it says props is not defined

Comment: @NicolásRiccardi well you don't want to remove the `import` otherwise you won't be able to use the action creator. 
You want to keep the import but then not destructure it in the props.
since you're using `combineReducers` then yes you also need to access the `data` state one level deeper. So like I mentioned it will be something like
`mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.promo.data
  })
`

Comment: given your devtools screenshot, your `mapStateToProps` will be
`mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.promo.data
  })
`

Comment: Thank you for your time ismael. Now im not destructuring getPromos func, but it seems like it never execs. 
Destructuring I get in my devTools the log from the action being called.
If I don't, data never updates . It looks like this:

const Landing = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPromos();

    console.log(props);
  }, []);

Comment: And my mapStateToProps like this: 
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  data: state.promo.data
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPromos }
)(Landing);

Comment: so the import should look like this:
`import { getPromos } from '../../actions/promo';`
and the component should look like this:
`const Landing = props => { useEffect(() => { props.getPromos(); console.log(props); }, [])`

Comment: Thanks! Worked smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jHxH.png)

Here's a screenshot of the redux dev tools